# Подстановка рандомного слова в цикле PHP

Tags: php

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при каждой новой обработки кода в цикле, в переменную .$rand_text. подставлялось из файла всегда новое рандомное значение, а не тоже самое?

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['btn-start'])){



       $title = $_POST['title'];
       $count = $_POST['count'];


     for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
       include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

       $file = "words_alpha.txt";
       $file_arr = file($file);
       shuffle($file_arr);
       while($x = array_pop($file_arr));

       $html = file_get_html('https://www.bing.com/news/search?q='.$x.'');



       // находим все ссылки
       foreach($html->find('div.news-card-body') as $element)

       $result.= $element->innertext. '<br>';
       require_once('template.php');

      // открываем файл, если файл не существует,
      //делается попытка создать его
      $fp = fopen("public/".rand().".html", "w");

      // записываем в файл текст
      fwrite($fp, $template);

      // закрываем
      fclose($fp);
      echo "<script>Swal.fire(
        'Файлы созданы!',
        'Продолжить работу!',
        'success'
      );</script>";

        if ($i == $count) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто:

- считываете данные из файла в массив.
- перемешиваете массив, например через **[shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php)** или с помощью какого-либо алгоритма
- в цикле пробегаетесь по массиву, например с конца и подставляете слово, удаляя элемент из массива

Comment: иными словами `$l = file(..); shuffle($l); while($x = array_pop($l)) echo $x;`

Comment: всё так сразу и вывалили козыри)

Comment: я теперь не успеваю ответы писать, так хоть код подкину :D

Comment: @teran рандом то работает, но так же, как и был. В цикле всё равно и тоже слово выбирается.

Comment: @hellokitViki не может оно выбираться одно и то же, если по это слово удаляется из массива. Оно может быть только если такое слово изначально было написано в файле не один раз

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в файле всего 5 слов

Comment: @hellokitViki это не важно. Смысл таков: в файле слова не должны повторяться. А если повторяются, то тогда в алгоритм добавляется момент по удалению дублей из массива. Второе и важное - на каждой итерации из массива должен удаляться элемент, с позиции которого был он взят... и `array_pop` вполне это делает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский повторных слов у меня нет

Comment: @hellokitViki покажите финальный код, который вы написали на основе моего ответа или комментария teran

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский 
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
       include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

       $file = "words_alpha.txt";
       $file_arr = file($file);
       shuffle($file_arr);
       while($x = array_pop($file_arr));

       $html = file_get_html('https://www.bing.com/news/search?q='.$x.'');

Comment: @hellokitViki тут не нужен внешний цикл

Comment: @hellokitViki давайте угадаю - всегда показывает последнее слово. Почему приведенный код с while стал вдруг пустым телом цикла?

Comment: @teran эмм...нет. Он выбирает рандомное слово, но только один раз.

Comment: @hellokitViki а да, там же shuffle есть. без него было бы последнее